# Using Java Selenium, how can I make Firefox open downloaded text files in a new window or tab?

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

We want to run Selenium tests in a grid environment, and so won't have access to read any downloaded files from the remote browsers. To be able to check the contents of some downloaded files with dynamic content, we thought we could configure the FirefoxProfile so that downloaded files of certain types open in a new tab, and then read the contents directly from the browser.

The files are downloaded upon submission of a form, and altering any of the form attributes is not an option, since we do not want to change the user experience.

I have found information on how to set the download folder and specify direct downloading of specified file types, but not how to do "the opposite".

Since I am able to specify this behavior when manually downloading these files, I assume there is a way of doing it programatically too.

The FirefoxProfile we use is new FirefoxProfile(), and not an imported profile from the file system.

My last attempt was something like this:

```
    FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile","text/csv, text/plain");
    return firefoxProfile;
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the File Path and Name then Open a new Instance of WebDriver or go to page in existing instance

Path file path

```
  String filePath = "file:///C:/Users/userdir/Documents/Logs/error.log"

  Using driver.get(path);
```

would open the txt file in a browser window.

Comment: This requires that you know the full file path, which might not be the case when running against a remote browser. Without the possibility of cleaning out old files at will, you would end up with error(321).log.

Comment: Setting a default download directory should be able to figure out where file is saved on remote browser
fProfile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", @your_preferred_dir);

Comment: Yes, but this does not help if the file gets renamed because it has already been downloaded to the same location by a different process.

Comment: Have a script that clears that directory every you are running a job, or prefix the directory everything you run your script.

Comment: This adds overhead and makes it difficult to achieve something that should be quite easy.

Comment: Well its only to avoid opening wrong file when already downloaded as you said.